# How to access a class attribute for method argument

Tags: python, class

```
class Matrix:

    decimals = True

    def __init__(self, decimals=decimals):

        if decimals:
            print('The matrix will have decimal values.')
        else:
            print('The matrix will have float values.')


Matrix.decimals = False
mat1 = Matrix()
```

**Output:**

```
The matrix will have decimal values.
```

I'm trying to make it to where I can change the value of `decimals` for all instances of a class while also using it as an argument in the `__init__` method. Why is the above not working?

Comment: It does not work because default values are defined (and set) at **function/method** definition time. When you set `Matrix.decimals = False`, `__init__.decimals`'s value is already set to `True`

Comment: In hindsight, that duplicate is probably not the best. If someone finds a better one, feel free to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default argument of `__init__` is evaluated when the method is *defined*. At this point the value of the variable is still `True`.

If you want the class variable to be evaluated when the method is *called*, it needs to be done inside the method body:

```
class Matrix:

    decimals = True

    def __init__(self, decimals=None):
        if decimals is None:
            decimals = self.decimals

        if decimals:
            print('The matrix will have decimal values.')
        else:
            print('The matrix will have float values.')


Matrix.decimals = False
mat1 = Matrix()
```

Output:

```
The matrix will have float values.
```

Comment: Thank you. That suggested question is different than what I am asking here. It deals more with the scope of inheritance, while my question here deals with the scope of class attributes.